# Would it be weird to try to consciously try to get the Peer Pressure badge?

Tags: discussion

The badge reads:

> Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower

If someone's trying to play the system, they could actually spam the system, make the typical "What icon would be suitable for...?" and get people to down-vote it and when it's good enough   delete the post.

What's the philosophy behind this badge?

Comment: The overall idea behind badges should be not to try to get them, but to get them by merit.

Comment: Now that you bring this up, I think I know someone who is actively trying to get this. At least that's a good explanation of that person's activity :)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah it's not really something you're supposed to *try* to get, like many of the badges it's just reinforcement for what you should do; if you have a bad post, maybe delete it. Even more confusing is the "tumbleweed" badge...which isn't even encouraging good behavior.

It would definitely not be a good idea to intentionally post poor content in the hopes of it getting downvoted so you can delete it. It's also not something I've seen very often either (that I've been aware of) so I don't think it's a big concern, either.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's a "pity" badge.

Honestly, there's hundreds of badges you COULD get once you factor in the tags, and it's not about trying to get them all -- you only see how many badges you get, not a percent complete. It's much more productive all around to try and get certain badge multiples (like "Nice Answer") than it is to produce crap to get the crap badges.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, these kinds of badges are the hardest ones for me to try to get. I'm something of a completionist when it comes to badges (and heck, trying to earn badges is why they exist; [they're all part of the gamification of the site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)).

It's definitely the case that if a badge is listed, I want to try to receive it, and the very existence of this badge is likely to make others that feel like me more inclined to do what's required to earn it (though not necessarily enough to actually do it).

For what it's worth, this badge and others like it have been debated on Meta.StackOverflow before:

- [Badges should reward positive behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107628/191347)
- [Flaw in the Peer Pressure badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126679/flaw-in-the-the-peer-pressure-badge)